# if f is integrable on [a,d]. Prove that f is also integrable on [b,c]

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose a<=b<=c<=d and f is integrable on [a,d]. Prove that f is also integrable on [b,c] . I am currently stuck on this problem. I have done a similar problem before where a function is integrable on [a,b] and [b,c] and I need to prove that it is integrable on [a,c]. I used the cauchy criterion for that one so show the difference between the upper and lower sum is less than epsilon so I assume we use the same method here.

So I start by stating the cauchy criterion for the interval [a,d] and then create a refinement, Q, that includes the points b and c. Now at this point I'm not sure how I can get to the inequality U(f,P)-L(f,P)<epsilon to finish the proof.